Generate TFW files without rewriting the GeoTIFF
I have about 20000 GeoTIFFs that I need to create tfw files for.  Is there an easy way to extract the georeferencing information from the GeoTIFFs and write the tfw file, without having to rewrite the original images (like gdal_translate -co tfw=yes does)?

@TomazicM that linked Q is currently closed for being unfocused (Q wants TFW and PRJ) so I think its okay to accept answers here.

You do not say which gis software you are using. If arcpro then look here.

@Hornbydd they mention gdal_translate so I assume they have a command-line somewhere, and understand that's the gdal tools, and so maybe can use the geotiff command-line tools also, as per my answer. We wait, its only been 12 hours...

Question Creating TFW and PRJ files for folder of GeoTIFF files? is reopened now.

The listgeo command from the geotiff-bin package (on Linux at least, not sure how you get this for Windows or Mac) does this:
$ listgeo -tfw ./accflow.tif
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered.
World file written to './accflow.tfw'.

$ more accflow.tfw 
           25.0000000000
            0.0000000000
            0.0000000000
          -25.0000000000
       266434.0257250000
      4464087.5000000000

